# html code in brackets

Tags: html, file, editor, adobe-brackets

I'm new in brackets software, I noticed that when I opened the new file, is showing no HTML code or any other code, just blank white page. Is not like Dreamweaver when open new file showing with HTML code.

I was wondering if there is possible for us to add HTML code in back on brackets file so that way when user open a new file, that comes with HTML code instead of writing from scratch.

It is possible to add HTML code somewhere, so the user can open the new file with HTML code!

AM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean that you want some basic pre-insertion of HTML code into your document, so you don't have to bother with manually typing in:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Title here</title>
</head>
<body>
.....
</body>
</html>
```

If that is the case, you can write up a template file, save that, and open it up later to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [emmet](http://docs.emmet.io/), It's available for all the polpular editors.
Than to start a new document just type `!` then press `tab`.
it will generate an `html5` template for you
!
Alias of html:5

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

This

```
#page>div.logo+ul#navigation>li*5>a{Item $}
```

...can be transformed into

```
<div id="page">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <ul id="navigation">
        <li><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Item 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Item 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```